# How to decode major and minor version nibble in C?

Tags: c, decode, ndef, nxp-microcontroller

I am currently working on an I2C communication between an i.MX6 (Android BSP) and a NTAG 5 boost component.

I would like to decode the Capability Container at block 0 of the NTAG 5 EEPROM.
I have written a C function that decodes the major and minor version of CC byte 1, as described in this table.

[image]

And here is my function:

```c
static char CH_version[4] = "0.0";

bool F_decodeVersion(NTAG_HANDLE_T ntag) {
    uint8_t UI_localVersionAccessCondition;
    bool B_status = false;

    /* Reads byte 1 */
    if (!F_readCCByte(ntag, VERSION_ACCESS_COND_BYTE, &UI_localVersionAccessCondition)) {
        B_status = false;
    }

    /* To get the high nibble corresponding to version, we shift the value
       four bits to the right */
    UI_localVersionAccessCondition = UI_localVersionAccessCondition >> 4;

    /* Decode */
    switch(UI_localVersionAccessCondition) {
        case 0x00:
            memcpy(CH_version, "0.0", 4);
            break;
        case 0x01:
            memcpy(CH_version, "0.1", 4);
            break;
        case 0x02:
            memcpy(CH_version, "0.2", 4);
            break;
        case 0x03:
            memcpy(CH_version, "0.3", 4);
            break;
        case 0x04:
            memcpy(CH_version, "1.0", 4);
            break;
        case 0x05:
            memcpy(CH_version, "1.1", 4);
            break;
        case 0x06:
            memcpy(CH_version, "1.2", 4);
            break;
        case 0x07:
            memcpy(CH_version, "1.3", 4);
            break;
        case 0x08:
            memcpy(CH_version, "2.0", 4);
            break;
        case 0x09:
            memcpy(CH_version, "2.1", 4);
            break;
        case 0x0A:
            memcpy(CH_version, "2.2", 4);
            break;
        case 0x0B:
            memcpy(CH_version, "2.3", 4);
            break;
        case 0x0C:
            memcpy(CH_version, "3.0", 4);
            break;
        case 0x0D:
            memcpy(CH_version, "3.1", 4);
            break;
        case 0x0E:
            memcpy(CH_version, "3.2", 4);
            break;
        case 0x0F:
            memcpy(CH_version, "3.3", 4);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm sure that's not the best way to decode this nibble.
I guess I should use the modulo operator.

How can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: This is crying out for a simple look-up table and use of `strncpy()` instead of `memcpy()`.

Comment: If those are bits you can just mask and test, like `b & 0b00110000` if you want it to be super clear, or `b & 0x30` otherwise. You can always shift over (`>> 4`) to get those zero-indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using just bitshifts and masking.

```
CH_version[0] = (UI_localVersionAccessCondition >> 6) & 0x3 + '0';
CH_version[1] = '.';
CH_version[2] = (UI_localVersionAccessCondition >> 4) & 0x3 + '0';
CH_version[3] = '\0';
```

Consider [not using global variables](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and doing `bool F_decodeVersion(NTAG_HANDLE_T ntag, char *CH_version);`

Comment: This uses "move and mask" which might be harder to follow than the "mask and move" approach where the mask aligns with the spec sheet more closely. Both approaches get precisely the same result, of course.

Comment: @KamilCuk But here I use a static global variable that can only be accessed by a getter that has the char *CH_version as a parameter. Is this also a bad way to program?

Comment: @MartinDenion If it's always the same value when you return it, then that's okay. The problem with global variables is when they change.